# Почему в JSON-поле 2 раза попадает одно и то же значение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

При вызове метода `update_state` хочу записывать в json-поле `state` элемент с некоторой датой, если его нет. Или обновлять дату, если такой элемент уже есть:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    state = db.Column(db.JSON, default={})

    def update_state(self, word_id, days=0):
        date = datetime.today() + timedelta(days=days)
        self.state.update({word_id: date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')})
        flag_modified(self, 'state')
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

Проблема в том, что если вызвать этот метод 2 раза с одним и тем же `word_id`, то в базу записывается дубль. В третий раз этого не происходит. Ну, например:

```js
{"1260": "2019-12-23", 
 "1497": "2019-12-23", 
 "1260": "2019-12-23"}
```

Почему так получается и что с этим делать?

Answer (score 3):

Дошло. Дело было в том, что `word_id` - это число, которое превращается в строку при записи в бд. И когда я добавляю туда еще один элемент с таким же id, то в словаре один из элементов с ключом-числом, а другой с ключом-строкой. При записи в бд они оба становятся строкой.